# sql query: how many col1 record of tab1 appears in col1 of tab2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a 2 tables with supplier ref as common column. now i want to know how many supplier ref from table1 appears in supplier ref of table2.

the data is stored in microsoft sql server

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: You can just inner join them. Then you know how many which matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query using **JOIN** to know the supplier ref from table1 appears in table2.

```
 SELECT a.supplier ref
 FROM a
 JOIN a1 ON a.supplier ref = a1.supplier ref;
```

Use **COUNT** to find the number of supplier ref from table1 appears in table2.

```
 SELECT count(*)
 FROM a
 JOIN a1 ON a.supplier ref = a1.supplier ref;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do that by using `INNER JOIN` as mentioned by @plainDK

```
SELECT t1.[supplier ref]
FROM Table2 t2
     INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.[supplier ref] = t2.[supplier ref];
```